# How to track if recipient click a link in email?

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

How to track if recipient click a link in  email ?. I know we can add an endpoint on our backend to track the clicks on those links and integrate it with the sending of emails - to know which link is from which email. But in my case I have CC email. So link url will be same for all recipients. Is there any way to identify each recipient clicks ? I am using nodemailer module to send emails.

Here is my code

```
  var  params = {
         from: fromAddress ,
         to: toAddresses,
         subject: subject,
         html: content,
         attachments: emailObj.attachments,
         cc = emailObj.cc_email,                                   
     };

     transporter.sendMail(params,function(error){
        if(error){
             console.log(error)
        } else{
             console.log('success')
        }
     });
```

Comment: Technically it should be related to referring document, mail clients normally have defense from that, for the privacy issues. Most of them even load html _only_ in limited fashion to prevent  anything to happen.